# Pushed UIViewController appears on the screen but the buttons from the pushing view remains active

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, ioio

I have an IOS application which has several views. In one of them I have a button action  that push another view that has several buttons that are not activated although the view appears in the screen. If I touch in an area that was part of the previous screen the control is passed to the previous view.

I have checked the view controller and the view has the correct Owner.

```
- (IBAction)touchupinsideMenu:(id)sender {
    self.navigationItem.title=@"Menu";
    self.SubmenuViewControllerVIP=[[ SubmenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SubmenuViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.SubmenuViewControllerVIP animated:YES];

}
```

------------ EDITED -----------------------

The pushed view is not responding to the buttons and the pushing view's buttons are still active although the view is shown in the screen.

Any Idea?
Thanks

Comment: Are you using storyboards?

Comment: Actually I am using storyboard for the initial views but this view I use XIB file.

Comment: Then you shouldn't use pushViewController. If you are adding a view, do addSubView.

Comment: SO I cannot use navigationcontroller in this case. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way of initiating a UIViewController to push:

```
UIViewController *SubmenuViewControllerVIP = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SubmenuViewController"];
```

You need to use storyboards, tho.

Comment: Can I mix storyboard and NIB files?

Comment: I moved to storyboard but the problem remains the same. The pushed view appears on the screen but the buttons from the pushing view(previous) remain active and the buttons of the current view are not activated

Comment: are you calling the new View Controller with Navigation Controller the way I said?

Comment: edit your question with more detail so I can help you.

Comment: Yes I am calling the way you told me.

Comment: [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"StoryboardPrincipal" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NovoVoo"];
    self.NovoVooVIP = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NovoVoo"];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden=true;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.NovoVooVIP animated:YES];

Comment: This is another view but with the same effect. The presenting view's buttons are not active. The pushing views' buttons are the ones active.

Comment: BTW, I am using storyboard as you suggested